# Existence of numbers such as $\pi^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, axioms

For my non-mathematics students (this particular class are computing), I would define $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ as the solution of the equation

$$nx=1,$$

and then

$$\frac{m}{n}=m\cdot \frac{1}{n}.$$

I like this because it defines fractions in terms of one, natural numbers and multiplication and it accounts for fraction arithmetic.

Sometimes I see the more practical student doesn't really go for my approach and says, e.g. I know what $\displaystyle \frac13$ is...

That is kind of off the point but while I accept his point, I would then ask myself what is, e.g. $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\pi}$ but, via the real number axioms, the solution of

$$\pi \cdot x=1.$$

My questions are,

> 1. To the 'constructionist' mathematicians... does $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\pi}$ exist?
> 2. How do you calculate it to an arbitrary number of digits?
> 3. Do you 'accept' $\pi\in\mathbb{R}$ but not $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\pi}$?

Feel free to substitute $\pi$ for your favourite irrational number (if you believe in them!).

I myself am perfectly happy with the number $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\pi}$ from the axioms of the real numbers but was interested in what other people thought.

Comment: What do you mean by "if you believe in irrational numbers"? It is not a belief, it is the way they are described! The same for $\frac{1}{\pi}$! It does exist by the way fraction and $\pi$ exist! You can also have $\pi^{\pi}$ if you want!

Comment: A good approximation to $\pi$ gives you a good approximation to $\frac 1\pi$ (for example $\frac1\pi\approx \frac7{22}$) so that the calculation of arbitrarily many digits is not more probölematic than wit $\pi$ ...

Comment: I don't consider myself a 'constructionist' mathematician, but I would encourage you to edit this question to ask something more specific (e.g. focus on how to calculate $\pi^{-1}$ "to an arbitrary number of digits").  Open-ended discussions are not a strong point of the Math.SE Q&A format.

Comment: @Martigan The ! at the end of "if you believe in them" is supposed to denote some sarcasm.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen This is the best answer I have seen so far.

Comment: @hardmath There are three specific questions in there.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Sorry... I did not pick this up! Not always easy to do...

Comment: @Martigan Yes I am sorry it wasn't clear.

Comment: I do not understand this question - it is two fluffy. I have two points-of-interest to add though. 1) Do you know about Dedekind cuts? These are a formal way of defining real numbers. 2) It is not always possible to compute real numbers - this was proven by Alan Turning (and, if I recall correctly, his paper is in Hawking's book *On the shoulder's of giants*). A quick proof: there are only countably many Turing machines, but uncountably many real numbers. Hence, not all real numbers are computable.

Comment: (Although as $\pi$ is computable then, as Hagen von Eitzen points out, so it $1/\pi$, and indeed off the top of my head, so is every element of the extension field $\mathbb{Q}[\pi]$.)

Comment: I know about Dedekind cuts and equivalence classes of Cauchy Sequences. But I am coming from the viewpoint of somebody who doesn't... what else could $\frac{1}{\pi}$ mean? Thank you for your second point. We have some ideas here of how to compute $\frac{1}{\pi}$ so that doesn't quite apply here but thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine we have a sequence of numbers:
$$\{3,3.1,3.14,3.141,3.1415\dots\}$$
(In fact, I could use *any* increasing sequence that approaches $\pi$.)

$\pi$ could be *defined* as the smallest number $x$ that is greater than all of those numbers. That is, I could define $\pi$ to be the smallest number that is greater than $3$, $3.1$, *and* $3.14$, and $3.1415$, etc.

(Obviously, if we restrict ourselves to the rationals, such a number does not exist. But there is a property of the real numbers, saying that any increasing and bounded sequence has an *supremum*—that is, a smallest possible number that is greater than every term in the sequence. This sequence is obviously increasing. It's bounded because each term is less than, say, $4$.)

Now, look at this sequence of numbers:
$$\left\{\frac13,\frac1{3.1},\frac1{3.14},\frac1{3.141},\frac1{3.1415}\dots\right\}$$
Each of those numbers "exist," because those are rational numbers (and we know how to take the reciprocal of a rational). Now, let me define $\frac1\pi$ to be the *largest* number that is smaller than each of those numbers.

(This is called the *infimum*. In the real number system, any decreasing and bounded-below sequence has one. This sequence is obviously decreasing. It's bounded-below because each term is greater than, say, $\frac14$.)

$\frac1\pi\approx.0.3183098862$.

Comment: One last thing—this relied on the existence of an increasing sequence that approaches $x$ (in this case, $x=\pi$). Proof that this sequence exists: Just write out the digits, like I did above.

Comment: I like this answer and it extends out Hagen's comment above... although it appeals to the completeness axiom rather than the multiplicative inverse axiom. Do you think you could replace the multiplicative inverse axiom using the completeness axiom like this?

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Yes, I believe that the completeness property implies the multiplicative inverse axiom for the reals. (Of course, I already assumed the multiplicative axiom for the rationals, which is easy to prove.)

Comment: Nice! I think this answers my question... if $\left|\pi-\frac{p_n}{10^n}\right|<\frac{1}{10^n}$ then $|10^n\pi-p_n|<1$. Because $1<\pi<10$ we have $p_n>10^{n}$ so $\left|\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{10^n}{p_n}\right|=\frac{|p_n-\pi 10^n|}{\pi p_n}<\frac{1}{10^n}$ and your answer gets accepted.

Answer (score 4):

The real numbers $\mathbb R$ are an example of a mathematical *field*. In other words, they satisfy a number of axioms (essentially, the basic laws of middle school mathematics (distributive property, commutative property of multiplication, etc...)). One of these field axioms is the following:

> For each nonzero $x\in\mathbb R$, there exists a number ${1\over x}\in\mathbb R$ such that $x\cdot {1\over x} = 1$.

This is essentially your question: the real numbers are defined as a certain field, and since $\pi$ is a real number it is guaranteed to come with a real number $1\over\pi$.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question I asked... I know what about what you wrote. This is why I have written "via the real number axioms"...

Comment: @JpMcCarthy As your question is currently worded, the only answers anyone can give are appealing to the real number axioms. For example, the other upvoted answer appeals to the least upper bound property which is a "real number axiom". These all guarantee the existence of $1/\pi$, what is there left to do?

Comment: Answer "How do you calculate it to an arbitrary number of digits?" for example... which two other users have done.

Comment: Related meta thread: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17079

Answer (score 2):

If you accept the relationship between algebra and geometry, you might argue like this:

[image: pi inv]

Every line $f(x) = a x$ with $a \ne 0$ has exactly one intersection with the line $g(x) = 1$.

Comment: Are you just saying that $f(x) = \pi x$ has exactly one intersection with $g(x) = 1$ so there is a unique solution to $\pi x = 1$? Also, there are arguments against accepting the relationship between algebra and geometry?